# Cant get tabs to display on every page. Ionic 7

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I have a tabs project and the pages in the tabs are working fine.
I have tab1, tab2, tab3

my problem is I also have a side menu and when I click on one the menu items called page1 it routes fine to page1 with the route tabs/page1  but the tabs are not displayed like they are on tab1, tab2 and tab3.  I would like to show the tabs one every page even if the page isn't on of the 3 tabs.

thanks in advance